# Python does not recognise a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I have a folder: backend/api

In the folder I have the following files:

```
❯ exa --tree
.
├── __init__.py
├── api.py
├── requirements.txt
└── routers
   ├── __init__.py
   └── phone.py
```

In the api.py I have the following:

from api.routers import phone

When I start up the file I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api.routers'; 'api' is not a package
```

Isn't placing an **init**.py file making a Python folder a package?

Answer (score 0):

The api.py is on the same level as the routers,

please try: `from routers import phone`

Note that the `routers` is a package in this case.